# Comunicación entre fragment

Tags: android-studio

Muy buenas comunidad, ahora realizando las pruebas y fallos, tengo cuatro fragment, por el cual voy desde el primero, al segundo, al tercero y al cuarto, todo bien hasta ahí, pero cuando vuelvo de este ultimo al primero me vuelve a consultar ¿Desea ingresar más mano de obra? y después ¿Desea ingresar mas repuestos?, por lo cual leyendo e investigando me dijeron a entender que debo hacer desde el primer fragment las comunicaciones con el segundo y tercer fragment: por lo cual realice lo siguiente, primero las declaraciones:

```
public class Segundo extends Fragment {
    private boolean consultaRealizada = false;
    public boolean isConsultaRealizada() {
        return consultaRealizada;
    }
    // Método para obtener el TableLayout desde el fragmento
    public TableLayout obtenerTablaDatos() {
        // Lógica para obtener el TableLayout aquí
        return obtenerTablaDatos();
    }
    // Método para obtener el TextView desde el fragmento
    public TextView obtenerTextoDetalle() {
        // Lógica para obtener el TextView aquí
        return obtenerTextoDetalle();
    }
}

public class Tercero extends Fragment {
    private boolean consultaRealizada = false;
    public boolean isConsultaRealizada() {
        return consultaRealizada;
    }
    // Método para obtener el TableLayout desde el fragmento
    public TableLayout obtenerTablaDatos() {
        // Lógica para obtener el TableLayout aquí
        return obtenerTablaDatos();
    }
    // Método para obtener el TextView desde el fragmento
    public TextView obtenerTextoDetalle() {
        // Lógica para obtener el TextView aquí
        return obtenerTextoDetalle();
    }
}
```

hasta ahí no tengo muchos problemas o dudas, el problema es aquí en el resume que se encuentra después del inflater:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Verifica si el campo txtpresupuesto1 está vacío y actualiza la disponibilidad de los botones
    if (txtpresupuesto1.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
        btn_modificar.setEnabled(false);
        btn_eliminar.setEnabled(false);
        btn_grabar.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        btn_modificar.setEnabled(true);
        btn_eliminar.setEnabled(true);
        btn_grabar.setEnabled(false);
    }
    Segundo segundo = (Segundo) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("segundo");
    if (segundo != null) {
        // Obtener tbldatos y txtdetalle desde el segundo fragmento
        TableLayout tbldatos = segundo.obtenerTablaDatos();
        TextView txtdetalle = segundo.obtenerTextoDetalle();
        // Verificar si los elementos están disponibles y no están vacíos
        if (tbldatos != null && txtdetalle != null && !txtdetalle.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            // Obtener la actividad que contiene el fragmento
            if (!segundo.consultaRealizada) {
                segundo.buscar1();
            }
        }
    }
    Tercero tercero = (Tercero) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tercero");
    if (tercero != null) {
        TableLayout tbldatos = tercero.obtenerTablaDatos();
        TextView txtrepuesto3 = tercero.obtenerTextoDetalle();
        if (tbldatos != null && txtrepuesto3 != null && !txtrepuesto3.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
            // Realizar la búsqueda si la consulta no ha sido realizada antes
            if (!tercero.consultaRealizada) {
                tercero.buscar4();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

el problema como puedo comunicarme desde el primer fragment al segundo ya que me da error en esta línea "segundo.buscar1();" y al igual que en el tercero "tercero.buscar4();", lo que pretendo que cuando se cumpla por ejemplo que tbldatos o txtdetalle del segundo fragment estén vacíos este se comunique con el fragment que corresponda y realiza el trabajo que debe hacer, eso es todo lo que se necesita, favor de ayudarme soy novato en estas lides y necesito ayuda de ustedes, desde ya muchas gracias.